# Enforce SageMaker Lifecycle configuration on Notebook Creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker

I want to make sure when someone on my team starts a SageMaker notebook, they attach a required lifecycle managment policy (called auto-kill-if-idle).

I have been able to enforce the desired SageMaker role and instance types via an IAM policy, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to inforce the lifecycle managment part. The goal is to not allow the notebook to start unless the correct lifecycle policy is enabled. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't give them permission to Edit or create notebook. They should be able to only start/stop the notebook instance. something like

{
"Sid": "LockDownCreateNotebookInstance",
"Effect": "Deny",
"Action": [
"sagemaker:CreateNotebookInstance"
],
"Resource": "*",